# Replacing known text in an unreliable string (OCR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocr, text-extraction

I have OCRed text from a form. I need to extract text that is often mixed in with headers and other extraneous (but known) text.

I have a box for **name** on the my form. I usually this get back from the OCR:

"Name: Some Name"

Here I can just remove "Name: " and continue my day.

Unfortunately, I often get stuff like this:

- "Name Some Name"
- "ame: Some Name"
- "ame Some Name"
- "Name. Some Name"
- "NameSome Name"
- "ameSome Name"

What are some techniques to clean up/extract desired text when you now the strings to remove but they are often mangled?

I'm using Javascript/Node.

Thanks

Comment: Is “Some Name” a variable or static text?

Comment: Some Name is variable text.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always expecting to get the label, or at least some part of it, you can try using a regex to match it, and remove.

Something like (transform it to lowercase first):

```
^n?ame[:.\-\s]?
```

Where you may or may not have a "n" at the start of the line, followed by "ame" and then a separating character like ": . or -"

This might not work for all cases, but it will work for the examples you've provided

Comment: Mr. Ames is not amused ;)

Comment: @Piskvorcc-by-sa3.0 Unless the label is not extracted at all I think Mr. Ames would be fine since the regex only catches the label at the line start, of course this does not cover all the cases though, it's a matter of tweaking the regex with the results of the extraction